# Need to validate a unique, specific value over multiple Select fields

Tags: jquery, select, validation

I have a form with set of dropdown fields, each of which has a default value of "0" and available values of 1-3. These are serving as a priority selection, where the user picks their top 3 items. Each select field name is unique and populated in a PHP foreach loop -- I'm just calling it "N" in the example below.

```
<select class="variable_priority unique required" name="select-N">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

The "0" value is used as the default/preset value for non-prioritized selections. Using the techniques [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955536/prevent-duplicate-values-using-jquery-validation), I have successfully modified JQuery Validate to ensure that the user cannot pick 1, 2 or 3 in more than one dropdown by comparing the class "variable_priority":

```
$('.variable_priority').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() === value && $(this).val() > 0) {
                timeRepeated++;
            }
        });
```

However, I still need to validate that the user has indeed entered a value of 1, 2 and 3 in any of the select fields, and has not skipped any. Can anyone give me some guidance on how to do this within the context of JQuery Validate?

Comment: Add up the values, ensure they're not all = 2

Comment: @Diodeus -- Thanks for the suggestion. I'm a JavaScript newbie, so is there a painless way to sum up a string of values based on selector? For example, in the answer below, based on select.variable_priority :selected. And I assume that it should be =6, i.e. 1+2+3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After re-working the requirement on JS Fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/halfcube/aLvc6/

I think this maybe more closer to your requirement

HTML

```
<div class="selects">
    <select class="variable_priority unique required" name="select[]" required>
        <option value="0">Select</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    <select class="variable_priority unique required" name="select[]" required>
        <option value="0">Select</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    <select class="variable_priority unique required" name="select[]" required>
        <option value="0">Select</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    <select class="variable_priority unique required" name="select[]" required>
        <option value="0">Select</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="value">
    0
</div>
```

CSS

```
.valid{
    box-shadow:0 0 10px green;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 10px green;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 10px green;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function checkSelected(val) {
        var ret = false;
        $(".variable_priority").each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() === val) {
                ret = true;
            }
        });
        return ret;
    }

    function totalValue() {
        var total = 0;
        $(".variable_priority:first option[value!=0]").each(function() {
            total = total + parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
        });
        return total;
    }
    function totalSelectedValue(){
        var total = 0;
        $(".variable_priority option:selected").each(function() {
            total = total + parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
        });
        return total;
    }
    $('.value').html(totalValue());
    $('.variable_priority').change(function() {
   //     variable_priority = variable_priority + parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
        $('.value').html(totalSelectedValue() + " out of " + totalValue());

        $('option', this).each(function() {
            if (checkSelected($(this).val()) && $(this).val() !== "0") {
                $('.variable_priority option[value=' + $(this).val() + ']').attr('disabled', true);
            } else {
                $('.variable_priority option[value=' + $(this).val() + ']').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        });
        if (totalSelectedValue() === totalValue()) {
            $('.selects').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
        } else {
            $('.selects').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
        }
    });
});
```

Now I must get back to work.

enjoy

Comment: Thank you so much for the work and insight. I love how it's working on the page and how you've integrated the different validations. However, as best as I can tell, because the <option> items with selected values (1,2,3) are set to "disabled", the information is not being passed on to my next form page with the $_POST data. I'm getting an array of five data sets with a value of 0, but not the 1,2 or 3. Any thoughts on how those values could be passed along?

Comment: Never mind - I was able to solve this using some binding code [found here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191113/disable-select-form-field-but-still-send-the-value/1191365#1191365):
    $('form').bind('submit', function() {
    $(this).find('option').removeAttr('disabled');
   });

Answer (score 0):

I would firstly get the browser to do most of the work, so I would use HTML5 attributes like `required` `disabled` and `selected` for good mesure.

You could try something like this.

```
<select class="variable_priority unique required" name="select-N" required>
  <option value="0" disabled></option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

This should be enough to allow the browser to show `blank` as the default value then once the user selects an option they can't select `blank` again.

For safe mesure I would put a JavaScript side validation binded to the form submit event to ensure the form is valid.

Something like this;

```
$("form").bind("submit",function(){
  if($("select.variable_priority :selected").length >= $("select.variable_priority").length){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
});
```

This if statement will check the count of `selected` dropdowns compared to the total number of dropdowns on the page. If they match then the form is valid.

I hope this helps you out.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. I'm not able to go to HTML5 quite yet, but I appreciate the insight. As for the validation code, I've tried this:

`if( $("select.variable_priority :selected").length == 8 )`

In my test case, my select object has 8 options. The script above only returns true if I have length==8. It should be length==3 to validate that three entries have been made, i.e. priority values 1, 2 and 3. I've modified my default option to not return a value (<option></option>), but somehow they're still being counted against the total :selected.

Comment: I'm getting the thought that your using a `<select>` with multi select. Is this correct?

Comment: No - sorry if I wasn't clear. In my test case, I have a set of eight <select> fields, each with values 0, 1, 2 or 3. I need the user to make selections in three of the fields, marking one of the fields "1", one of them "2" and one "3". No dupes and all three values must be chosen, leaving the others at "0". I got the validation working by summing the values of the answers and returning false until they =6 (1+2+3). It works, but the error messaging is handled on a field level rather than globally, so it's somewhat kludgey. Plus I have to use a separate validation for the unique answer req.

Comment: Here is the validation used for testing the specific values:
`  varsum: function (value, element) {
   var sumOfValues=0;
   $(".variable_priority").each(function(){
    sumOfValues+=Number($(this).val());
   });

   if(sumOfValues==6){
    return true
   } else { 
    return false
   }
  },`

Comment: Here is the validation used for testing the unique values:

`  unique: function (value, element) {
   var parentForm = $(element).closest('form');
   var timeRepeated = 0;
   $('.variable_priority').each(function () {
    if ($(this).val() === value && $(this).val() > 0) {
    timeRepeated++;
    }
   });
   if (timeRepeated === 1 || timeRepeated === 0) {
    return true
   } else { 
    return false
   }
  },`

Comment: FWIW, the specific value validation is based on a technique [described here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225121/jquery-validate-sum-of-multiple-input-values).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>$(document).ready(function() {
$('select').change(function() {
    $('option[value=' + $(this).val() + ']').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

});